# What is the theoretical relationship between sound and mass with respect to the sound barrier as a max velocity?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, aerodynamics

First post here, forgive me any faux-pas. In regards to compressible flow and accelerating a mass flow, such as in a converging nozzle, I know that you can't accelerate a mass past the speed of sound (Mach 1, that is, the velocity at which an infinitesimally small mechanical wave would propagate itself through the same medium, i.e. the mass of air itself). So, you need a diverging section to allow you to continue to de-pressurize the mass and continue to convert its enthalpy into kinetic energy (velocity).

I know *how* this works, via the following equation (and its analogues):

[image]

and I understand choked flow and all sorts of analogies for how much mass flow could be possible (traffic jams, etc). My question is more of a *why*. Why is the speed of *sound* the max velocity of some given mass at the throat?

At first, that was my question, then, I recognized that sound is just a wave of pressure difference - so then, I asked, what is the relationship between pressure and mass? Well, pressure is force over area, and force is mass accelerated - so is that the key to the relationship? But pressure has no mass - so then do I have to treat the mass flow as a wave (like in wave-particle duality for matter)? I think by this point I've gone way too far and missed something simple.

So, why the "speed of sound"? Why pressure waves, instead of electromagnetic waves, or some arbitrary constant with respect to the medium? What does the velocity of pressure have to do with the velocity of matter in this context?

Comment: A decent text book will explain this... or your lecturer should....

Comment: Would...you be able to?

Comment: Possible hint:  what is carrying the sound wave, and how fast is that carrier moving?

Comment: I am happy to help, but first I would like to understand your sentence: "Why is the speed of sound the max velocity of some given mass at the throat?" better. The critical (M=1) values are no tight to mass. The area and density and velocity ratios are given and the mass flow can be computed. But as I said I am not sure if I got your question in the first place.